# convert html file to BytesIO then pass as Flask variable

Tags: python, pandas, bytesio

I'm trying to convert a HTML file to BytesIO so that I don't need to write the file in the filesystem and get it from memory instead. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288614/how-to-pass-image-from-memory-to-flask-variable) about converting image to BytesIO however I can't apply it to HTML file.

I'm using Flask as my framework.

What i have tried:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()

merged_df.to_html(buffer, encoding = 'utf-8', table_uuid = 'seasonality_table')
buffer.seek(0)
html_memory = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())

return render_template('summary_01.html', html_data = html_memory.decode('utf-8'))
```

then in the HTML code which I want to output the html file:

```
<img id="picture" src="data:html;base64, {{ html_data }}">
```

Error message I got =
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

Comment: I don't understand how you want to display `HTML` as `image` `<img>`. It is totally wrong idea. You should put HTML directly without `<img>` - ie. `{{ html_data | safe }}`

Comment: you have to read data - `html_memory.read().decode(...)`. But frankly you can get HTML without using file - simply `html = merged_df.to_html()` without filename nor buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: using `<img>` to display HTML is totally wrong idea.
Tag `<img>` is only for images like `PNG`, `JPG`, etc.

You can get directly HTML using `to_html()` without `filename`

```
html = merged_df.to_html(table_id='seasonality_table')
```

and send this as HTML

```
return render_template('summary_01.html', html_data=html)
```

and you need `safe` to display it as HTML

```
{{ html_data | safe }}
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to put data as file for downloading then you should use `<a>` instead of `<img>` and it may need `application/octet-stream` instead of `html` to start downloading it.

```
html = merged_df.to_html(table_id='seasonality_table')
html = base64.b64encode(html.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

return render_template('summary_01.html', html_data=html)
```

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,{{ html_data }}">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

---

Minimal working example

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import pandas as pd
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    data = {
        'A': [1,2,3], 
        'B': [4,5,6], 
        'C': [7,8,9]
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    html = df.to_html(table_id='seasonality_table')
    
    html_base64 = base64.b64encode(html.encode()).decode()
    
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

{{ html_data | safe }}

<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,{{ html_base64 }}">DOWNLOAD</a>

</body>
</html>''', html_data=html, html_base64=html_base64)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    #app.run(threaded=False, processes=3)
    #app.run(use_reloader=False)
    app.run()
```

Comment: OMG it works! yes you're right we can just use to_html() without a filename. A follow up question: the format I set using Pandas styler looks to be gone using this method. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't remeber details but it may need to assign styled data frame to variable `styled_df` and use  `styled_df.to_html()` to get HTML from styles dataframe. Similar problem was few weeks ago in some question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: [python - how to Send dataframe as html table with font styling based on text value as a email attachment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068186/how-to-send-dataframe-as-html-table-with-font-styling-based-on-text-value-as-a-e/)